# Selecting members to add to a github project

Tags: git, github, collaboration

My team recently added a software project to github. We are getting requests from some of the users that they would like to become part of the team. What would be a good way to choose whom to add ?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't add any outside contributor right away - make them send pull requests instead. As you review these pull requests, you can:

- Assess the skill of the contributor from the quality of their code
- Verify that what they want to add to the project is compatible with your vision
- See how willing they are to conform to your rules and style
- Learn to know them a bit by talking to them over the comments in the review-fix cycle

After accepting a few of their pull requests, you'll be in a much better position to decide if you want to give to a contributor push access to the project's repository.

Note that the contributors also learn during the course of the pull requests, so these parameters can and will improve over time. A contributor can learn from your code review how code submitted to the project should be and match their code to it. So it's not a matter of *who* but a matter of *when* (where the answer can be "never", but you don't know that yet) - any contributor might one day be a full member.